# How to call an app with no-route from another app in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Here is usecase:

I have two apps in Bluemix: app1 and app2

app1 is accessible through the internet using its route (e.g. app1.mybluemix.net)

app2 doesn't have any route to prevent from being accessible through the internet.

app2 may expose a REST API.

How do I call app2 from app1 inside Bluemix?

Answer (score 6):

An example of communicating to an application without a route is implemented in this [Microservice Shipping sample](https://hub.jazz.net/project/rvennam/Microservices_Shipping/overview).

This is an EJB Liberty application that runs on Bluemix without a route and subscribes to the Bluemix MQ Light service. The sender of the messages is the [Microservice Orders sample](https://hub.jazz.net/project/ajlohr/Microservices_OrdersAPI/overview) application, which binds to the same MQ Light service.

Going the REST API route will mean you must have an externally accessible route. However, you could secure it using keys and tokens.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to use one of the services in Bluemix as an "RPC" layer between the two applications. You could use one of the queue services (MQLight, RabbitMQ) or [Redis](https://github.com/nfarring/redisrpc) to pass messages between the applications to execute commands.

These service bindings are internal and won't be exposed externally unlike the REST API.

Alternatively, you could expose the REST API from App2 and use authentication to control access.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can prevent access.

1. Put your microservice inside a Bluemix Container and utilize private IPs https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_security_network.html#container_cli_ips_byoip
   Use API Connect as a API Gateway/proxy to the private IP being  in your container microservice.
2. Use Bluemix Dedicated to deploy app2. Bluemix dedicated provides firewall capabilities and you could set it up so that it only accepts requests from app1's IP address.
3. Use Bluemix Local when it becomes available with the same approach where you use your corporate firewall to only accept requests that come from your App1 IP Address.  This is an expensive alternative compared to a public PAAS.
4. Use the [API Connect Service which replaced the API Management Service](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/APIManagement/index.html#gettingstartedapim) to:

   - Specify what users can access your apis
   - Specify the number of requests per day or other unit of time
   - Provides a API Gateway to securely call the other service App2.

I expect at some point a software network defined solution will be considered as part of the offering.